# I want to insert a word after first word

Tags: awk, sed

I just want to add "myword" after first word.

My file contains:

```
2222 'abc xyz bc'
3333 'hz naa jjja llll'
```

I want to make it to:

```
2222 myword 'abc xyz bc'
3333 myword 'hz naa jjja llll'
```

How can i do it via sed/awk or any?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed 's/^\( *[^ ]\+\)/\1 myword/' file
2222 myword 'abc xyz bc'
3333 myword 'hz naa jjja llll'
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk '{$1=$1" myword"}1' file
2222 myword 'abc xyz bc'
3333 myword 'hz naa jjja llll'
```

Comment: can you please explain the above sed ?

Comment: @ArtistIn `^` starting with. `\(` start of group. `<space>*` Does line starts with one or more spaces? `[^ ]\+` continue with all that is not space. `\)` end of group. (this will capture first word) `\1` use data from group `1` and add `myworld`.  `awk` is easy to understand and use, so if its not a problem that space in front of text and double spaces and tabs are gone, use it.

Comment: If you use the `-r`, you does not need to escape the parentheses. `sed -r 's/(^ *[^ ]* )/\1myworld /' file`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+/& myword/' file
```

Replace first word by itself ,a space and `myword`.

Answer (score 0):

try bash

```
while read line; do echo "${line%% *} word ${line#* }"; done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\b/ word/2' file
```

Substitutes the second word boundary (a zero-size match) with  `word`.

Requires GNU sed for `s///2` syntax.   For 2nd, 3rd word, etc, use ordinal*2.   So `s///4` to replace after 2nd words, `s///6` to replace after 3rd.